# Asp.net mvc call entity db data using Id for that particular row

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi and thank you for taking your time to read. I am having trouble calling from a db using entity framework for a particular row. Here is my code for controller.

```
public ActionResult MyAccount(CurrentAccount ca, SaverAccount sa, int id)
    {
        var model = db.CurrentAccounts.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == id);

        Session["Id"] = ca.Id;
        Session["CurrentAccountNumber"] = ca.CurrentAccountNumber;
        Session["CurrentBalance"] = ca.CurrentBalance;
        Session["SaverAccountNumber"] = sa.SaverAccountNumber;
        Session["CurrentBalance"] = sa.SaverAccountNumber;

        return View(model);



    }
```

My model is a edmx entity file and i can seem to retrieve some data to my locals but only from 1 table and i need data to be from multiple tables selecting a full row of data for a paricular Id then having this information visable  on the same view. There is also a relation between id on both tables. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the problem here. Are you getting an error? what is the desired behavior?

Comment: I want to use id to call view so /Accounts/MyAccount/1 in address bar but i need the other information that is sent to views to be specific to the rows of data that correspond with that id.

Comment: provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem so that better answers can be derived. as it currently stands it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is here.  "I don't know Entity Framework" isn't really a question we can answer.  There are tutorials to help with that.  The code provided doesn't look wrong to me.

Comment: How is it not clear? i need 2 tables rows from model.edmx/CurrentAccount.cs and model.edmx/SaverAccount file to controller then to a view that is specific to id?

Comment: code returns the id value but no values for the rest as im not asking the db to select row by id that is my problem the values are not retrieved.

Comment: Why can't you ask the db to retrieve the row for the specified Id. You have CurrentAccount and SaveAccount objects being passed in the method but you are not doing anything with them except storing in session. If you already have object of CurrentAccount then why ask db to retrieve it again?

Comment: Why you don't use eager loading of related objects?

Comment: Im new to asp.net so i will have a read over eager loading. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have called wrong object because you are fetching data in model variable but calling from ca. please use as following

```
public ActionResult MyAccount(CurrentAccount ca, SaverAccount sa, int id)
{
    var model = db.CurrentAccounts.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == id);
    Session["Id"] = model.Id;
    Session["CurrentAccountNumber"] = model.CurrentAccountNumber;
    Session["CurrentBalance"] = model.CurrentBalance;
    Session["SaverAccountNumber"] = sa.SaverAccountNumber;
    Session["CurrentBalance"] = sa.SaverAccountNumber;
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jyoti and this approach works fine for CurrentAccounts and has helped alot however i still cannot return the Saver Account details to the view that correspond with the same id as Current Account.

Comment: Here you are only fetching data from CurrentAccount you need to get data from Saver account with Id save as you have done for CurrentAccount.

var savermodel = db.SaverAccount.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == id);

Comment: I tried this and it does work but I cannot return 2 different models to view at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute join query to get data from two models like following exmaple

Create a common class like follwing

```
public class datafrombothclass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String saveaccount_name { get; set; }
    public String currrentaccount_name { get; set; }
}
```

Now use join query in entity framework to get data from both model in you case from CurrentAccount and SaverAccount. 
See the bellow code example:

```
var frombothclass=(from a in Model.saveaccount join s in Model.currentaccountaccount 
                           where a.Id=id 
                           select new datafrombothclass{
                               Id=a.Id,
                               saveaccount_name=s.name,
                               currrentaccount_name=a.name
                           });
        return View(frombothclass);
```

Hope you will get the solution.